# How to open file when user click's on notification in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am displaying notifications of file download to user in android.

Now I want to open that file when user clicks on that notification.

I have made the open file method it works fine. I just don't know how to set click listener on notification to call this method.

**My Notification Creator Method**

```
public void displayFileDownloadNotification(Context context, String fileName)
    {
        new CommonMethod().createNotificationChannel(context);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.cghs_launcher_logo);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.cghs_launcher_logo));
        builder.setContentTitle("CGHS");
        builder.setContentText("Downloaded "+fileName);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, builder.build());
    }

    public void createNotificationChannel(Context context)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            CharSequence name = "Attachment Download Notification";
            String description = "Simple Description";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }
```

**And my file open method**

```
public static void openDownloadedFile(String fileName, Context context)
    {
        try{
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().concat("/Download/" + fileName);
            Log.e("File Path=",path);
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Intent target = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
                try {
                    context.startActivity(target);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("File = ", "File does not exits");
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error ",e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Now how can I call this **openDownloadedFile**, when notifications are clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new Activity
   Call `openDownloadedFile` in OnCreate
2. Edit your notify:

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
> PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
> builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just had to make minor adjustments "FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" instead of "FLAG_ONE_SHOT", as I had multiple notifications at the same time.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, OpenNotification.class);
        intent.putExtra("fileName", fileName);
        intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);